# Proxy errors when trying to connect to Bitbucket from MercurialEclipse in Domino Designer

Tags: lotus-notes, bitbucket, mercurialeclipse

If I try to push my changes to the remote Bitbucket repository, using the url they provide for the repo, over https, I get the following:

> comparing with https://url-of-bickbucket.org abort: error: _ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol. Command line: C:\Program Files\IBM\Notes\Data\workspace\Broodjes\hg -y outgoing --style C:\Program Files\IBM\Notes\Data\workspace.metadata.plugins\com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse\log_style_with_files https://***@bitbucket.org/mvereecken/arcelor-broodjes

I tried using http://... also as remote location, but then I get:

> comparing with http://url-of-bitbucket.org abort: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  ). Command line: C:\Program Files\IBM\Notes\Data\workspace\Broodjes\hg -y outgoing --style C:\Program Files\IBM\Notes\Data\workspace.metadata.plugins\com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse\log_style_with_files http://***@bitbucket.org/mvereecken/arcelor-broodjes

I'm at the company, so I have to pass the proxy server, and it is automatically detected in IE using a script.  However, in Eclipse (at least the Domino Designer version) no proxy settings can be set.

Does anybody have an idea how to pass the proxy here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse if you go to Window -> Preferences and then type "proxy" in the filter you should see some proxy configuration. MercurialEclipse should pick up these settings.

If Domino Designer somehow doesn't have this preference then you could configure proxy settings at the Mercurial level. For example see this configuration: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#http-proxy

However I don't know if Bitbucket will accept authenticated requests on http (rather than https).

Comment: John, proxy settings are not part of Domino Designer, so it seems (only in standard Eclipse). So this is not a valid option.

Trying to change the Mercurial proxy settings didn't work either... I've abandoned the Mercurial solution as a SVN option now, in favour of CIAO!, not only because of this, but because of the best integration with Domino Designer.  Thanks anyway!